# whats the best way to connect Actionscript 3 in flash to a database?

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, flash, phpmyadmin, adobe

I am currently creating a platform side-scrolling game. I want to know if is there some kind of tutorial where you can connect AS3 in flash cc to a database server because this is for my high score section and I looked online and majority of the tutorials I found barely work anymore. Is there a way to do it using MySQL and phpMyAdmin?

Comment: If you are planning it for web, you will need a server-side script where you will send the data to. That script will then write the DB. You cannot use mysql from flash player directly.

Comment: yes i am making a flash game for web, what would be the best way to do it? should i make the table in myphpadmin first? and then code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly!
You can view the flash var concept [Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)

So, in my particular instance I created an .asp page that was connected to a database and had the .swf in the same page surround by the flash published object tag. I then fed in a courseNum variable in the url header, that allowed me to get specific data from the database.

Now that I knew I could connect to my db, I had to create external variables for Flash to communicate with the db information. In order to do that, you need to follow the this particular parameter syntax, and insert this into your object tag.

```
<param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye" />
```

Where as myVariable and MySecondVariable denotes the value you want to pass to flash.



In my particular case I used:

```
response.Write("<param name=FlashVars value='courseNum="&(RS1.Fields.Item("courseNum").Value)&"'/>"))
```

Which wrote `<param name=FlashVars value="courseNum=000"/>` into the object tag.

Now that I had everything set up on my page. I could then go into flash and communicate with these variables using:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.courseNum;
```

again making sure I was matching the variable name listed in my flash vars(courseNum) with the same parameter name in my flash code. And that's all there is to it. Just simulate this same process of:

1. Creating a page that can talk to the database
2. Implement your flash file into the page via the object tag
3. Write the flashvar param syntax to your object tag using PHP writing methods(not sure what those are echo maybe??)
4. And allow flash to communicate to this information using `var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable;` with "myVariable" matching what you have listed in your flashvars object tag variable name.

Hope this helps in some way, take care!

Comment: thanks, ill give this a try and will get back to you :)

Comment: Was this particular question answered to your satisfaction? If so could you please close out and comment any solutions you used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is to use php on server side, and just call the created scripts.

In **php** you create connection with database.

And from AS3 you just pass *parameters* through **HTTP GET** or **POST** methods.

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1--active-5147) you have a nice tutorial

[and here](https://www.developphp.com/video/Flash/Two-Way-Flash-AS3-and-PHP-Communication)  is a video tutorial

Hope that helps...

Comment: I used flashvars to feed db data into flash via asp for a project. I would try to look into this option.

Comment: @hexobolic is there any tutorials for it? I am interested to see how its done